# Digital Signature: Certificate of a Signer using SignServer Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, digital-certificate, electronic-signature

I have a requirement to create digital signature on behalf of client using SignServer. I am a little bit confused regarding 2 issues.

1. Does every client requires a unique certificate or can a single certificate be used for all?
2. Can I create digital signature certificates using SignServer because I can't find anything like that in their documents. If No, what is the suggested way to create digital signature certificates from a server side application?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Does every client requires a unique certificate or can a single certificate be used for all?

I didn't know this project, but reading the [documentation](https://www.signserver.org/)

> SignServer is a server side signing server. Individual signing keys for every user or one central key for the organization

So, depends on your needs. If you want to identify every signer use individual certificates. In other case use a central certificate. But not that the certificates are stored in a central server. They are not distributed to users. You will need a central repository. It is recommended to use cryptographic hardware (HSM). And you will need to generate credentials to user so they can use the certificates

> 2) Can I create digital signature certificates using SignServer because I can't find anything like that in their documents. If No, what is the suggested way to create digital signature certificates from a server side application?

Usually signature solutions are not coupled with the Public Key Certificate Authority to issue certificates. Take a look to this links

- **EJBCA**: https://www.ejbca.org/ A known PKI Certificate Authority software to issue certificates. It is a J2EE opensource solution
- **Expert PKI tutorial**: It is a set of scripts based on OpenSSL to stablish a Certificate Authority

Of course, you can also build your own integrated solution using [Bouncycastle](http://bouncycastle.org). Choose it depending on the number of certificates to issue and the complexity of your CA

Answer (score 1):

This question has also been answered in the [SignServer discussion forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/signserver/discussion/668766/thread/cd25b6f6/#2255):

> Multiple signers can share the same key-pair and certificate. Simply point them to the same crypto token and key and configure the same certificate for them.
>
> Certificates are not intended to be created by SignServer. After generating a key-pair you can get a certificate signing request (CSR) that you can bring to a Certificate Authority (CA) which can issue a certificate for you.
>
> For testing, or in case you don't have a CA in your organization and if you don't want to buy a certificate from a commercial CA, you can set up your own PKI using software like EJBCA ([ejbca.org](https://ejbca.org)) or OpenSSL.

Answer (score -2):

As signature has to be passed through network, we convert into string but we cant use just string of original byte array because of security. Hence we do manipulation of byte array and convert into a different string.
We should not send new String(byte [] signature), we should send  new String(Base64.encode(byte[] signature))

formula is : data.getByte() + private key à signature

More you can learn from it, 
the link is very helpful.
http://javaint4bytes.blogspot.com/2018/04/java-signature-certificates.html

Comment: please learn how good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer